# Django + react js

Tags: django, reactjs

Как прилепить правильно react js к готовому Django проекту?

Comment: В АНБ этому не учат? Обычно, через шаблоны. В чем сложности?

Comment: К готовому скорее всего будет не легко. Django + ReactJS в идеале это когда Django отдает только REST API (тоесть исключительно backend), ну а ReactJS лежит отдельно и только делает запросы к этим API посредством ajax